# How can I modify the size of fraction?

Tags: amsmath

```
$ \hat{Y}=\ln{\frac{Y}{Y^*}} $
```

When I took a log on fraction, the size of this fraction is too small to see.

I don't want the size of the fraction to decrease.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The usual `\ln` does not take an argument, and it has not impact on the size of the fraction. The reason that the fraction is small is because you are in "in-line math mode". You can force the fraction to be the same size as that in "display math mode" if you use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`.

Comment: Or you could just use `(Y/Y^*)`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome :) // If you'd provide us your code, as it is normal to do in this place (copy&run), we could learn easily, whether or not you are trying to use a font size like 4pt or so ... or if your preamble suggests other problems. Thanks

Comment: you are using _inline_ math (`$`) that is designed to fit in a line of text without changing the line spacing. Perhaps you want display math `\[\hat{Y}=\ln \frac{Y}{Y^*} \]`

Comment: THANKS EVERYBODY!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your assertion that the fraction expression produced by `$\ln{\frac{Y}{Y^*}}$` is smaller than the one produced by `$\frac{Y}{Y^*}$` is unsupported.

Before proceeding to a discussion of how you might generate a larger fraction expression, it's worth recapping (a) how TeX's four basic math *styles* -- `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle` -- are related to font *sizes*, and (b) how TeX decides which math style should be applied to the numerator and denominator portions of `\frac{...}{...}`.

- When TeX is inside a displayed equation, the basic math style is (unsurprisingly?) `\displaystyle`. The easiest way to set up a displayed equation is to encase a formula in a `\[ ... \]` "wrapper".
- When TeX is in inline math mode -- as is the case for an expression such as `$\hat{Y}=\ln\frac{Y}{Y^*}$` -- TeX employs `\textstyle` as the basic math style. To initiate and terminate inline math mode, use either `$ ... $` or `\( ... \)`.
- When TeX is in either `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`, first level superscript and subscript terms are processed in `\scripstyle` mode, while second-level subscript and superscript terms are processed in `\scriptscriptstyle` mode.
- About font sizes: Ordinary symbols, such as Latin and Greek letters, get the same font size irrespective of whether `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle` is in effect. ("Large operator" symbols, such as `\sum`, `\prod`, and `\int`, are produced at a larger size if `\displaystyle` is in effect.) `\scriptsize` produces letters that are 30% smaller than those produced if `\normalsize` is in effect, and `\scriptscriptsize` is 30% smaller than `\scriptscripsize`. (Allowing for some minor rounding, it can be said that `\scriptscriptsize` is 50% smaller than `\normalsize`.)
- When TeX encounters a `\frac{...}{...}` expression, the math style applied to the numerator and denominator terms is one step "down" from  the basic math style. E.g., in the inline equation

  ```
  $\hat{Y}=\ln \frac{Y}{Y^*}$
  ```

  the letter `Y` in `\hat{Y}` is processed in `\textstyle` and is rendered at  `\normalsize`, whereas the letters `Y` in the numerator and the denominator are processed in `\scriptstyle` -- to be exact, the denominator is processed in "cramped script style" -- and are rendered at `\scriptsize`.

[image]

- To render the letter `Y` in the numerator and denominator at the same size as `\hat{Y}`, it's necessary to switch to `\displaystyle`, either for the `\frac` term or for the whole inline equation. (Recall that the same font size is applied to letters in both `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`.) To use displaystyle just for the fraction term, one can write either `{\displaystyle\frac{Y}{Y^*}}` or -- if the `amsmath` package is loaded -- `\dfrac{Y}{Y^*}`.

[image]

- A brief moment of reflection reveals that it may well be a *very bad idea* to use `\dfrac` in inline math expressions. Indeed, it may be a *much better idea* to switch from `\frac` (or `\dfrac`!) notation to "inline fraction" notation, aka "slash style" fraction notation: `$\hat{Y}=\ln (Y/Y^*)$`.

[image]

Do note that that all three instances of `Y` are rendered at the same size -- which, I gather, was one of your typesetting objectives.

---

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%$ \hat{Y}=\ln\frac{Y}{Y^*} $%
%$ \hat{Y}=\ln\dfrac{Y}{Y^*} $%
$ \hat{Y}=\ln(Y/Y^*) $
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, wonderful explanation!

Comment: @Zarko - Many  thanks!